# R markdown multiple tab does not generated in HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have used R markdown to generate multiple tabs in order to save different charts
[image]

It works in the markdown file. But after I knit it to HTML, the two charts are not in different tabs. Instead they are arranged vertically without any tab.
[image]
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the headers (**##** and **###***) outside of the chunks.

For example (In your Rmarkdown please delete the *"("* and the *")"* from the **##** and **###** lines):

(## Quarterly Results {.tabset})

(### By Product)

````
```{r}
Your Code
```
````

(### By Region)

````
```{r}
Your Code
```
````

See [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#tabbed-sections)

Notice that a Rmd document is basically markdown syntax with R code in the form of chunks.  See [this](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html)